# Animate children of container

Tags: javascript, createjs

I want to tween elements inside a container. The elements will be added in a for loop. Once they have been added I know that they are on the stage I then want to animate the elements in individually with a delay so that the first element animates in first then the second etc etc.

```
 addElements();

 function addElements(){
      var total = arr.length; 
      var _cont = new createjs.Container(); 
      stage.addChild(_cont) 

      for(var      i=0;i<total;i++){ 
           //add children to _cont 
      } 

      animateIn(); 
 }

 function animateIn(){
 //I now want to tween each element in _cont individually

 }
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the animateIn function below.

```
 function animateIn(obj){
        Debugger.log("Animate In");

        for(i=0;i<obj.getNumChildren();i++){
            obj.getChildAt(i).alpha = 0;
            createjs.Tween.get(obj.getChildAt(i)).wait(i*100).to({alpha:1}, 1000)
        }
 }
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < childElementCount; i++)
    {
    setTimeout (<animate function in context of current child>, i*<duration of your animation>);
    }
```

Comment: Thx, i*<duration was very useful.